# Is there any Google Now API that we can integrate our own Apps into Now?

Tags: android, google-now

How can I provide my information or cards of my App-Data to Google Now?
Is there any API that I can use?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no public API available YET for Google Now for android. Reasons unknown, better read [this article](http://www.extremetech.com/mobile/198618-google-now-has-opened-up-to-third-party-developers) but it is planned to be released according to this [article](http://www.wired.com/2015/03/open-google-now-make-android-super-smart/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google Now API is only provided for who register their app with Google, it has been private. Google control which Cards will be shown on their Google Now App. So you need to contact with Google and register your app to get the Now API and then you can build your own Now Card.

Comment: Any updates on this? Did a Google search and doesn't look like the Now API has been made public yet.

Comment: I think they don't have a plan to public it. They control the data sent to Now API very strictly.