# How to use Google Now to set alarms and reminders through 3rd party app

Tags: android, alarm, reminders, google-now

I've developed an Android alarm clock/reminder app and I'd like to know if there is a way possible to make Google Now at least prompt the user whether they want to set the alarm/reminder either through the default app or mine.

Comment: Did you at least find this in your research: https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/system/

Comment: I think it'll help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32371952/is-there-any-google-now-api-that-we-can-integrate-our-own-apps-into-now

Comment: @MorrisonChang I researched a lot but didn't come across that one. I might have used the wrong keywords.
The link you sent me is exactly what I need, please post it as an answer so I can close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe sounds achievable with Google System Voice Actions. It is a bit different than Google Now, the anticipatory cards UI, but as Google Now is shown with the speech recognition part that may explain the confusion when searching.

See: [Google System Voice Actions](https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/system)

Unfortunately only a fixed set of voice actions (system actions) currently are supported: 
https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/custom-actions