# Sending text extras from Google Assistant to Android app

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk

Is there any way to sending intents with text extras to my android app from Google Assistant? 
Example:
I'm saying to assistant: "Hej, write my note I want to do it"
Response: "Okay, I've written I want to do it in your app"

An activity is started and EditText contains "I want to do it".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Google Now to set alarms and reminders through 3rd party app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41745879/how-to-use-google-now-to-set-alarms-and-reminders-through-3rd-party-app)

Comment: Fortunately your example of 'take a note' is a supported system action for [Google Voice Action](https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/system/)